# Windows 2008 IIS 7 PHP Caching / Blank Page Problems?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, php, iis-7

I don't even know how to explain this. The only thing I can think is 'why am I working with a windows server?'

I am renting a dedicated 1and1 server - I installed PHP myself - with fast CGI and caching (pretty sure I checked OK on something about dynamic caching for PHP when I installed it.)

Every few hours of intensive php processing - my pages start locking up - usually just showing blank pages - with no errors whatsoever.

Just now, I checked a page - let's call it **a.php** - and it was showing the results of **b.php** - I thought I had been hacked!

Simply restarting the IIS server however, fixes the problem.

Any ideas / help / knowledge on similar problems with windows 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have gone through the article [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/). Unless there is some missing/miss configuration in .php I have never seen IIS serving wrong pages. You can certainly check IIS logfiles to verify the same.
Don't want to frustrate you but we happen to overlook lot of things specially when working with new environment like IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the page swapping problem, but I had the exact same problem about blank pages, I struggled with it for weeks. What I did was go into the FastCGI settings and drop the number of pages served by each instance to about 100, and the problem is "solved". Not to my satisfaction, but it hasn't come up since.

J.Ja